# Disable Bluetooth headset for some users

Tags: windows-10, bluetooth, user-accounts, headset

In our family, we have a few Bluetooth headsets. We also share a family Windows 10 pc (a surface pro) that we all have a personal account on. I want to prevent (for example) my headset from connecting to the family pc when my son is using it on his account. So depending on the user, I want to configure whether a Bluetooth headset will connect or not. Is this possible in Windows 10?

Thanks!